# Restart a process if it is running in Bash

Tags: bash, grep, kill, restart

Hi Im trying to check a process is running, and if it is, restart it. But if it isn't, start it. The script is run after a batch of commands have been executed remotely from a windows machine using Plink. Then I run another plink command to run this script. The application  on the host machine is running continuosly.

```
SERVICE="./Snowflake.app/Contents/MacOS/Snowflake"

if pgrep "$SERVICE" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; 
then
echo "$SERVICE is running"
pkill "$SERVICE"
 else
  /Applications/snowflake/run.sh

fi
```

The problem here is that if the application is open it doesnt close it, but instead opens the application a second time. Can anyone tell me where Im going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to simply, stupidly kill the process and check the error message like `No process found` (which is not really an error in this case).

Every attempt to check whether the process is running before killing it would be prone to a race condition, meaning the process might start right after your check.

Comment: Oh sorry I had to put in pkill a second time, yes you're right it is stupid.

Comment: Actually it is *not stupid*. It's safe against race conditions.. :)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that u have send all output from the pgrep to /dev/null
Leave that simple out and it will work. (tested!)

Comment: Redirecting the output of a command does not change the value of `$?`, which is what `if` is checking.